# TCPDF QR-code in footer?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using PHP script TCPDF..
Is there a way, that I can put QR-Code in footer of PDF file?

This is how I used it to display on a page(not in footer or header)

```
$pdf->write2DBarcode('www.tcpdf.org', 'QRCODE,L', 20, 30, 50, 50, $style, 'N');
$pdf->Text(20, 25, 'QRCODE L');
```

Comment: Did you look at their [demos](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)? There's a QR example with source code, and ones that show how to do a footer...?

Comment: So you managed finally to copy over those two lines from the demo #50? Sorry, but you need to tell more about what does not work for you and what the error is. Maybe you just need to try a little bit harder and that's all to solve this "issue"?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that is perfectly possible, it's in the examples:

```
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_050.pdf
```

By definition there is no such thing as an explicit "footer" in a PDF file, it's just rendered at a specific place. So put it at the lace where you put the "footer".

Your code looks fine (but only if your whole code is more than these two lines which I assume).

Answer (score 1):

My problem was, that I was calling variable from class - that didn't work. I needed to create constant outside class.

```
define('NASLOV', $naslov_pdf_poln);
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

//Page header
public function Header() {
    // Logo
    $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo_mali.jpg';
    $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '',     false, false, 0, false, false, false);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(0, 15, 'Ultimate Basketball Stats', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
    $this->Cell(0,21, 'Ultimate Basketball Stats', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
}

// Page footer
public function Footer() {
    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Set font


    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    $this->write2DBarcode(NASLOV,'DATAMATRIX', 100, 265, 25, 25, $style, 'N');

    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 10, NASLOV, 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
}
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very long time till Gregor message... 
In your Footer() function you are using $style which was probably been set in your main code. But it cant' be seen inside the function of the Class.
In order to be able to use it inside the Footer() function, you must declare it as "global". So:

```
     public function Footer()
      {
       global $style;

       // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but just in case someone lands here.

You can make use of  `$pdf->setBarcode( 'abcdef' );` and by default the barcode will be included in the PDF footer as 1DBarcode. In my case I preferred to have the barcode as a QR Code in the header next to the logo and customised the default Header and Footer as per below:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    /**
     * This method is used to render the page header.
     * It is automatically called by AddPage() and could be overwritten in your own inherited class.
     * @public
     */
    public function Header() {
        $barcode = $this->getBarcode();
        if ( $this->header_xobjid === false ) {
            // start a new XObject Template
            $this->header_xobjid = $this->startTemplate( $this->w, $this->tMargin );
            $headerfont          = $this->getHeaderFont();
            $headerdata          = $this->getHeaderData();
            $this->y             = $this->header_margin;
            if ( $this->rtl ) {
                $this->x = $this->w - $this->original_rMargin;
            } else {
                $this->x = $this->original_lMargin;
            }
            if ( ( $headerdata['logo'] ) AND ( $headerdata['logo'] != K_BLANK_IMAGE ) ) {
                $imgtype = TCPDF_IMAGES::getImageFileType( K_PATH_IMAGES . $headerdata['logo'] );
                if ( ( $imgtype == 'eps' ) OR ( $imgtype == 'ai' ) ) {
                    $this->ImageEps( K_PATH_IMAGES . $headerdata['logo'], '', '', $headerdata['logo_width'] );
                } elseif ( $imgtype == 'svg' ) {
                    $this->ImageSVG( K_PATH_IMAGES . $headerdata['logo'], '', '', $headerdata['logo_width'] );
                } else {
                    $this->Image( K_PATH_IMAGES . $headerdata['logo'], '', '', $headerdata['logo_width'] );
                }
                $imgy = $this->getImageRBY();
            } else {
                $imgy = $this->y;
            }
            $cell_height = $this->getCellHeight( $headerfont[2] / $this->k );
            // set starting margin for text data cell
            if ( $this->getRTL() ) {
                $header_x = $this->original_rMargin + ( $headerdata['logo_width'] * 1.1 );
            } else {
                $header_x = $this->original_lMargin + ( $headerdata['logo_width'] * 1.1 );
            }
            $cw = $this->w - $this->original_lMargin - $this->original_rMargin - ( $headerdata['logo_width'] * 1.1 );
            $this->SetTextColorArray( $this->header_text_color );

            if ( ! empty( $barcode ) ) {
                $this->write2DBarcode( $barcode, 'QRCODE,H', $headerdata['logo_width'] + 20, '', 12, 12, [], '' );
            }

            // header title
            $this->SetFont( $headerfont[0], 'B', $headerfont[2] + 1 );
            $this->SetX( $header_x );
            $this->Cell( $cw, $cell_height, $headerdata['title'], 0, 1, 'R', 0, '', 0 );
            // header string
            $this->SetFont( $headerfont[0], $headerfont[1], $headerfont[2] );
            $this->SetX( $header_x );
            $this->MultiCell( $cw, $cell_height, $headerdata['string'], 0, 'R', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false );

            // print an ending header line
            $this->SetLineStyle( [
                'width' => 0.85 / $this->k,
                'cap'   => 'butt',
                'join'  => 'miter',
                'dash'  => 0,
                'color' => $headerdata['line_color']
            ] );
            $this->SetY( ( 2.835 / $this->k ) + max( $imgy, $this->y ) );
            if ( $this->rtl ) {
                $this->SetX( $this->original_rMargin );
            } else {
                $this->SetX( $this->original_lMargin );
            }
            $this->Cell( ( $this->w - $this->original_lMargin - $this->original_rMargin ), 0, '', 'T', 0, 'C' );
            $this->endTemplate();
        }
        // print header template
        $x = 0;
        $dx = 0;
        if ( ! $this->header_xobj_autoreset AND $this->booklet AND ( ( $this->page % 2 ) == 0 ) ) {
            // adjust margins for booklet mode
            $dx = ( $this->original_lMargin - $this->original_rMargin );
        }
        if ( $this->rtl ) {
            $x = $this->w + $dx;
        } else {
            $x = 0 + $dx;
        }
        $this->printTemplate( $this->header_xobjid, $x, 0, 0, 0, '', '', false );
        if ( $this->header_xobj_autoreset ) {
            // reset header xobject template at each page
            $this->header_xobjid = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to render the page footer.
     * It is automatically called by AddPage() and could be overwritten in your own inherited class.
     * @public
     */
    public function Footer() {
        $cur_y = $this->y;
        $this->SetTextColorArray( $this->footer_text_color );
        //set style for cell border
        $line_width = ( 0.85 / $this->k );
        $this->SetLineStyle( [
            'width' => $line_width,
            'cap'   => 'butt',
            'join'  => 'miter',
            'dash'  => 0,
            'color' => $this->footer_line_color
        ] );
        $w_page = isset( $this->l['w_page'] ) ? $this->l['w_page'] . ' ' : '';
        if ( empty( $this->pagegroups ) ) {
            $pagenumtxt = $w_page . $this->getAliasNumPage() . ' / ' . $this->getAliasNbPages();
        } else {
            $pagenumtxt = $w_page . $this->getPageNumGroupAlias() . ' / ' . $this->getPageGroupAlias();
        }
        $this->SetY( $cur_y );
        //Print page number
        if ( $this->getRTL() ) {
            $this->SetX( $this->original_rMargin );
            $this->Cell( 0, 0, $pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'L' );
        } else {
            $this->SetX( $this->original_lMargin );
            $this->Cell( 0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift() . $pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'R' );
        }
    }

}
```

In order to make use of the custom header and footer you need to do the below:

```
$pdf = new MYPDF( PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false );
$pdf->setBarcode( 'abcdef );
//Keep on building the pdf as usual
```